# Spring MVC: make helloworld app in eclipse but facing 404 error

Tags: eclipse, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to make helloworld app in eclipse but now i am facing 404 error.

url error:- localhost:8080/SpringDemo4/ HTTP Status 404 - /SpringDemo4/

Console error:-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

class:-HelloController.java

```
    package com.Rita.DAO;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework !");
        return "hello";
    }
    }
```

xml file in web-inf:-HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.Rita.DAO" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Web.xml

```
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>

    <param-name>HelloWeb123</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>

    </context-param>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

index.jsp

```
    <body>
    <a href="hello.jsp">Click on Page</a>
    </body>
```

hello.jsp

```
    <body>
    <h2>${message}</h2>
    </body>
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

added 1 jar in lib folder with BuildPath :- org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.release.jar

Comment: Many more spring jars are required.  try a google search for "jars required for spring mvc"

Answer (score 0):

Change link in your jsp page:  `<a href="/hello">Click on Page</a>`

Your requestMapping  is  `@RequestMapping("/hello")`, while you are trying to invoke 'hello.jsp' which is not mapped by your controller.